# Check if daylist has several days in a row

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I'm programming in c#.
I got a list of `DateTimes`, which could be like this (I'm only interested in the days):

```
12/07/2013,
12/07/2013,
12/06/2013,
12/05/2013,
12/04/2013,
12/04/2013,
11/11/2013,
11/10/2013,
11/04/2013.
```

In other words the daylist can contain more of the same date. The days are representing measurements and thats why it can contain more of the same day. 
I need to check if the daylist has lets say **3 consecutive days**:

```
11/11/2013,
11/10/2013,
11/09/2013.
```

My code looks like this:

```
public static void longTimeAnalyse(string cpr)
    {
        List<DateTime> dayList = getDaylist(cpr);
        dayList.sort();
        DateTime current = DateTime.now.Date;

        if(dayList.count() != 0)
        {
            //check in the dayList if there is any days in a row?? How do i do that?
        }
    }
```

Comment: `3 days in a row` meaning? three consecutive days or same days in a row thrice?

Comment: do you mean 3 repeated days? or 3 of any? and you should put sample of you code

Comment: 1. Make a new list<TimeSpan>
2. For loop from second element to last element.  For each add a new timespan from the current element to the previous one.
3.  Loop through the timespans and add up how many have a timespan of one day, reset the counter to 0 when it isn't. Keep track of the max consecutive days.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287590(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Sample data does not contain 11/09/2013.

Comment: @Derek Hmm Am I right if I say that the procedure you gave me only returns me if the list has 2 days in a row and not 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an extension method that will return any number of consecutive days in a collection:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<DateTime>> GetConsecutiveDays(this IEnumerable<DateTime> data,
                                                                        int consecutiveDayCount)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        }

        if (consecutiveDayCount < 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("consecutiveDayCount should be greater than 1");
        }

        var days = data.Select(item => item.Date).Distinct().OrderBy(item => item);

        return days.Select((day, index) => days.Skip(index).Take(consecutiveDayCount).ToList())
                   .Where(group => group.First().AddDays(consecutiveDayCount - 1) == group.Last());
    }
}
```

Test method (uses NUnit and FluentAssertions):

```
[TestFixture]
public class ConsecutiveDaysTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ConsecutiveDayTest()
    {
        var dayList = new List<DateTime>
        {
            new DateTime(2013,12,07),
            new DateTime(2013,12,07),
            new DateTime(2013,12,06),
            new DateTime(2013,12,05),
            new DateTime(2013,12,04),
            new DateTime(2013,12,04),
            new DateTime(2013,11,11),
            new DateTime(2013,11,10),
            new DateTime(2013,11,04)
        };


        var result = dayList.GetConsecutiveDays(3).ToList();

        result.Should().HaveCount(2);
        result.First().ShouldBeEquivalentTo(new[]{new DateTime(2013,12,06),
                                                  new DateTime(2013,12,05),
                                                  new DateTime(2013,12,04)});
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with me. I have done like this
`public static void longTimeAnalyse1(string cpr)
        {
            var result = EnumerableExtensions.GetConsecutiveDays(getDaylist1(cpr),3).ToList();
        }`
And called it from the constructor with a **string cpr** input.

Comment: I need the method to return true or false if the dayList has 3 or more  consecutive days. I'm quite new to programming sry for that.

Comment: @n.Stenvang Use this: `getDaylist1(cpr).GetConsecutiveDays(3).Any();`